# How to install Emmet (or any web development Plugins) for vim editor

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to develop my Website but I am not interested on using graphical interfaces. I would like to use vim only. I went on this page http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981, but, I am not sure how to proceed. any tutorials or step by step guide will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

to install emmet on vim

#### step one - install pathogen

install [tim pope's pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) this is needed to autoload the emmet plugin

copy and paste this into a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

add this to your `.vimrc`

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

If you're brand new to Vim and lacking a `vimrc`, run

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

and paste in the following super-minimal example:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

#### Step 2 - install emmet

copy and paste this into your terminal

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim.git
```

this will install [emmet for vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim)

---

You now should have emmet, go into an HTML file and type

`div.main`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

note you only have less than a second to hit the <kbd>,</kbd> after you've hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> or else emmet won't do anything.

Comment: I did the first step and I got this: No command ' curl' found, did you mean:
 Command 'curl' from package 'curl' (main)
 curl: command not found. Should I just copy and paste the command?

Comment: oh yeah you need curl, l'll update my answer now

Comment: I have a question: if I go on /etc/vim/vimrc and do a cat on that file. this is what I get:  " " Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif

Comment: wait, I thhink I found it in home directory as hidden. I was going into /etc.

Comment: There's no reason to use `curl` here. `wget` comes pre-installed and will work just as well.

Comment: hey guys, I have a question: I have a directory called .vim within my /home directory. within that directory I found my /autoload and /bundle directories, however, In my /home directory, I also have another file called .vimrc which is the one where I need to enter the command given in the instructions of the firs step. and It supposedly went through, however, I am not sure if it works.

Comment: @KenSandoval  `pathogen` is a kind of "behind the scenes" autoloader you probably won't see any indication that you installed pathogen correctly, until you complete the entire guide - if emmet works - you know pathogen worked .

Comment: hey, I'd like to ask you how can I download Bootstrap on vim, or, where would I downloaded it into?